# Dynamically changing a prop value for an external Vue.js 2.x component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I'm using the Tabs component from BootstrapVue within my site and i want to dynamically change the "disabled" prop from a tab component.

Unfortunately this isn't possible because "disabled" is defined as a prop within BootstrapVue and a prop is interchangeable within Vue.js while a data attribute is.

https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/docs/components/tabs

```
<b-tabs>
  <b-tab title="first" active>
    I'm the first fading tab
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="second">
    I'm the second tab content
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="disabled" disabled>
    <b-card>I'm the card in tab</b-card>
  </b-tab>
```

I think this problem isn't specific to this Bootstrap Tab component, but it's a broader problem when using external components. I don't want to modify the original source but i want to be able to change props of it.

I thought maybe using something like this. But that doesn't work. Also this won't make it capable for other tabs to change the state because it's bound to  non-indexed based property.

```
<b-tab title="second" :disabled="$parent.$parent.disabled">
```

Does someone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: why do you use $parent.$parent.disabled? Don't you have the disabled property in the data() of the component inside which you render the tabs ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem as well. See the simple fiddle I made and tell me if there is something more: https://jsfiddle.net/eacc6jpq/

Comment: Interesting. Anyway, my approach is a little bit more relevant to this https://jsfiddle.net/kxfzr9so/1/ where i use a own component because all my tabs needs buttons below them. I simplified in this case. Within my own project i use a *.Vue component for the template instead of defining it through it's property. Locally i get a "Property or method "disabled" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option." error.

Comment: then you should use props and events instead.

Comment: I'm afraid i have to make changes to the BootstrapVue component then because it's missing events for my needs. Im not to sure about that

Answer (score 1):

if you do this

```
<tab-content>
    <something :disabled="disabled"></something>
</tab-content>
```

then the "disabled" value is from inside the component from which you render the tab-content component, and does not belong to the tab-content component

You can't do this the way you want.

Comment: That what i was afraid for. So only solution is to fork BootstrapVue so i can fit it to my needs? Hmm...